# ASP.NET Web UI ListView won't refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

So I'm using ASP.NET with C#. And I have an  item that is queried from the database and displays items correctly.

I made a comment table, where user enters a piece of text, and presses an AJAX-enhanced button, to insert the comment into the database, which the table listview below displays.

However, when the user enters a comment, the table stays the same, it doesn't refresh. If I press Post a comment again, then it will display the previous comment, but not the current one.

I tried on the "post a comment" button to add the following:

```
    CommentsView.DataBind();
```

No luck, it won't refresh. And some smart programmer at microsoft forgot to add a simple "**ListView.Refresh()**" function to ListView class.

I don't understand why AJAX doesn't automatically update the table to update the information. How do you get it to display the latest data?

Comment: Did you update CommentsView.DataSource after the user enters a comment?

Comment: Which AJAX implementation are you using? If you're using Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX, you probably should wrap an UpdatePanel around the ListView so that you can trigger an update of the ListView by refreshing the UpdatePanel.

Comment: "..some smart programmer at microsoft.."  Sarcasm on SO often does not go over well -- unless you are on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: KBoek, yes I am wrapping it with UpdatePanel, but it's updating the previous comment after each button-click, not the latest one added to database.

Comment: Don't take my sarcasm so seriously Hogan, I'm just angry that everything in ASP.NET is slow, cumbersome, and not straightforward compared to interpreted languages.

Comment: @Dexter : Clearly I didn't, since I made the crack about meta -- but maybe that was too meta for a new user to get.  Seriously tho, I've found that jokes are rarely appreciated on SO much to my chagrin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those smart programmers at microsoft understand how databind works on apsx pages.

This involves understanding the page [lifecycycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  If you read this documentation and understand it, the problem  you are having should become clear.

But the quick answer is this:  Right now you bind to the data in the page init.  If you want that data to change you must rebind to the datasource.  .NET automagically caches it for you in the viewstate otherwise.

Add some code to your "Post a comment" to rebind the datasource (and thus change the viewstate) and you should be fine.

Comment: Of course they would understand, they created it. I get that it is in cache. However, I thought pageLoad would load again and requery the data. I made a function to requery the data and put in a new databind. Thanks.

Comment: @Dexter : not just in a cache -- in the viewstate.  Viewstate is very different than cache and is key to understanding how ASP.NET works.  Read this for good times : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, isn't viewstate same as cache? Why would they be different?

Comment: hmmm... viewstate is more like a variable that is passed back and forth between the server and the browser to preserve state.  A cache is a stored version of something that is retrieved instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

> listView.DataBind()

to update the listview.

Comment: I had to also wrap the listview in an UpdatePanel, probably because the DataBind() was triggered via an event from a control inside an UpdatePanel in a User Control.